# Breakpoint debugging minfied/mangled/compiled variables

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, source-maps, babeljs

Working on building JavaScript sourcemaps into my workflow and I've been looking for some documentation on a particular part of debugging source maps. In the picture below I'm running compressed Javascript code, but through the magic of source maps Chrome debugger was able to reconstruct the seemingly uncompressed code for me to debug:

[image: Source Maps]

However, if you look at the local variables, `someNumber` and `someOtherNumber` are not defined. Instead, we have `a` and `r`, which are the compiled variable names for this function. This is the same for both Mozilla Firefox and Chrome.

I tried looking through the [Chrome DevTools Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#source-maps) on sourcemaps, but I didn't see anything written about this. Is it a current limitation of sourcemap debugging and are there any workarounds for this?

**update**:

I've since found [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=327092) in chromium project issues. It doesn't look like it has been or is being implemented. This is becoming an increasingly more important problem as teams are beginning to implement Babel in their build systems to write ES2015 code. Have any teams found a way around this?

Comment: Can you provide files to test locally?

Comment: Here's an example of a site using source maps: http://dev.fontdragr.com/
You should be able to put a breakpoint in any of the JavaScript source file functions and replicate the behavior.

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems like Chrome really doesn't support variables mapping for now.

Comment: It is pretty amazing that this hasn't made it into Chrome yet. It used to be an annoyance, but with complex build processes and ES6 module transpilation, you can have name mangling even in unminified code.

Comment: @syarul - I don't think you've understood the purpose of source maps. Source maps and automated testing is not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @jBoive forget my comment, that's not going to solve this issue anyway, I haven't stumble upon this yet, as soon I made discovery maybe I can clear thing of better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's been addressed and will become available [in the next Chromium update](https://codereview.chromium.org/1770263002)

Comment: so... two years later, and it still hasn't landed?

Answer (score 3):

Using `Watch Expressions` on the right hand side, *usually* solves this.
Expand the menu, and use the plus button to add your variables.
You can use `someNumber` and `someOtherNumber`, and even `someNumber + someOtherNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

There's still no solution to mapping variable names in Javascript source maps, but there's a solution for Babel 6. As we've adopted ES2015, the mangled import names became a major pain point during development. So I created an alternative to the CommonJS module transform that does not change the import names called [babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs-simple](https://github.com/jamietre/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs-simple).

As long as you aren't writing modules that depend on exporting [dynamic bindings](http://www.2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html) it is a drop-in replacement for the default babel commonjs module transform:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs-simple
```

and `.babelrc`:

```
"plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs-simple"]
```

This will compile ES2015 modules to CommonJS without changing any of the symbol names of imported modules. Caveats are described in the readme.

This won't help you with minifying/uglifying, though, so the best solution seems to be to just don't use minification during development. Then at least it's only a problem if you have to debug something on a production web site.